# Sqlite data update

Tags: sqlite

I am designing a small app to assist my wife with her business. One of the things i need to do is to be able to update a table. Currently when I enter my update statement the database doesn't save the new data.

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE services
(
    location TEXT, 
    service TEXT, 
    price FLOAT, 
    commission FLOAT, 
    description TEXT, 

    PRIMARY KEY(location, service)
);
```

Update query:

```
UPDATE services 
SET commission = 0.690000 AND price = 165.000000 
WHERE location = "City" 
  AND service = "Board";

SELECT * FROM services;

City|Board|155.0|1.0|BANDT
```

I am using python3 and PyQt for the gui but I don't think they are the root cause. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: remove `and` from `set commission=0.690000 and price=165.000000` and replace it with a `,`.

Comment: AHHHH i knew it was something simple. Thank You!